# Meteor-Random - How to know if strong or weak generator

Tags: javascript, meteor, random

The meteor documentation at http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/random says:

> ... It uses a cryptographically **strong** pseudorandom number generator **when possible**, but **falls back to a weaker** random number generator when cryptographically strong randomness is not available (on older browsers or on servers that don't have enough entropy to seed the cryptographically strong generator).

**Q:** May I get somewhere in my scripts the information if generating a strong random generator is available or not.

I would like to show a box like: "Sorry you can not generate strong randoms within your environment" instead of creating weaker ones.

Thanks for some feedback
Tom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, thanks for your guide assistance but non of your posts answered the question as I would like to do it.

@Oskar: Your long (typeof...) test should work but this is not testing the Random package from meteor but the browser interface.

Unfortunately the `.type` property is not available at the `Random` object.

To use the Random object you have to use:

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
    if (Random && Random.alea) {
         // only weak
    } else {
         // strong via browser crypto
    } 
}
```

Cheers
Tom

---

UPDATE: My answer from above is only correct if you use a meteor release <1.2. There was an update since 1.2 so that now the property `.type` is available.

You still may use the test as above but now also:

```
if (Random.type === "NODE_CRYPTO") {
  // server side strong node crypto
}
else
if (Random.type === "BROWSER_CRYPTO") {
  // client side strong browser crypto
}
else {
  // weak crypto by alea()
}
```

Comment: Btw.: should be same on server. when not alea then using node-crypto.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the code:
 https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/random/random.js

I see a 'type' property of the Random object that indicates what sort of random number generator is being used.

Values extracted:

- NODE_CRYPTO - uses Node.js RNG - presumably *not* ever in the browser
- BROWSER_CRYPTO - uses Web Browser's random number generator - presumed to be string
- ALEA - the 'insecure' random number generator implement in JavaScript

So, you would check the random number generator being used by querying the "Random.type" value for one of those strings.

Answer (score 0):

[If the user is using IE10 or lower, Meteor falls back to Alea.](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/random/random.js#L244-L249)

The code used to check whether they have to use Alea or not is the following:

```
if (typeof window !== "undefined" && window.crypto && window.crypto.getRandomValues) {
    // We don't have to use Alea (strong)
} else {
    // We have to use Alea (weak)
}
```

You can either use the same `if`, or you can just do the following:

```
if(Random.type === 'ALEA'){
    // weak
}
```

Comment: [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#search=crypto) shows what browsers support `crypto.getRandomValues()`